# Laravel resource toArray() not working properly

Tags: php, laravel

I've created a new API resource called `UserResource`:

```
class UserResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        /** @var User $this */
        return [
            'first_name' => $this->first_name,
            'last_name' => $this->last_name,
            'email_verified_at' => $this->email_verified_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

And then I'm trying to get current user object and pass it to the resource:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $request->user();

        return new UserResource($user);
    }
}
```

But it always throws an exception `Trying to get property 'first_name' of non-object`. `$user` variable contains current user.

I'm using Xdebug and I checked that the resource contains formatted json in `$this->resource`, but not current user's model:
[image]

So why? Laravel's documentation says that I'll be able to get current resource (`User` model in my case) in `$this->resource` parameter, but it does not work. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** here is break point for xbedug in `UserResource`:
[image]

Comment: `$resource` should be the model instance not JSON which would be a string which isn't an object ... where did you set the break point to inspect that variable? or the other option is when you get that error there is no authenticated user and you are passing `null` to the resource

Comment: @lagbox yes, sure. It's very strange that I'm receiving JSON in `$this->resource`. I've already checked that `$user` inside the controller contains correct `User` model. So I have no idea what's wrong here.

Comment: where did you set the break point?

Comment: @lagbox I set the break point at `return` statement in `toArray()` method of the resource. So it is stopping before `return` statement executes

Comment: @lagbox I've added screenshot with the break point to the question's body

Comment: you need to find a point before that as you know it is the wrong type at this point because of the error, i might go into the `JsonResource` that it extends and set it in the constructor and keep stepping through until that variable changes to a string containing JSON

Comment: @lagbox yes, that's the clearest way to find it. I hoped that someone already met this problem, but I didn't find any solution for this case.

Comment: you didn't do something like `return new UserResource("$user");`  by mistake?

Comment: @lagbox no, of course :)  there's current controller's code in the body of the question

Comment: `$user = $request->user();` , this $user maybe not as your excepted, can you check it?

Comment: @liquid207 I checked it and it contains correct `App\Models\User` object

Comment: The only way I could reproduce this is by force casting to string `$user = (string) $user; // $user = "$user";` or in the **JsonResource** `public function __construct(string $resource)` But I see no where else this could suddently be encoded as `json` . Did you add a package that could replace the default `JsonResource` ? Maybe try re-installing the vendor

Answer (score 0):

It seems strange to me that you get the `User` object from the index's request and I reckon that somethings probably wrong there.

Normally, the index method is used to return a listing of all instances of the resp. model, e.g. something like

```
public function index() {
    return UserResource::collection(User::all());
}
```

Try to return a user object (as resource) which you are sure exists

```
$user = Users::findOrFail(1);
return new UserResource($user);
```

and see if the error still persists. If it does not, something is wrong with the data you pass in the request.

Comment: I tried it now and it does not work as well. There's the same error: `Trying to get property 'first_name' of non-object`

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the JsonResource Class. Look at the contructor:

```
public function __construct($resource)
    {
        $this->resource = $resource;
    }
```

Seems like the $user is saved to $this->resource. So you have to change your return statement to:

```
    return [
        'first_name' => $this->resource->first_name,
        'last_name' => $this->resource->last_name,
        'email_verified_at' => $this->resource->email_verified_at,
    ];
```

Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

As @Clément Baconnier said in comments to the question, the right way to fix it is reinstalling vendor folder. The problem is that project has been created via `Laravel new` command from local with php 7.2, but there's php 7.4 in container.